# how i can show random products on home page in shopify

Tags: shopify

Product should be changed on page refresh

Please check below code

```
<div id="showcase">
{% if collections.frontpage-1.products.size > 0 %}
{% capture index %}{{ 'now' | date: '%S' | times: collections.frontpage-1.products.size | divided_by: 60 }}{% endcapture %}
{% for product in collections.frontpage-1.products offset:index limit:1 %}
{% include 'product-list-repeatable-item' with product %}
{% endfor %}
{% else %}
<p>
<a href="/admin/custom_collections">
Add a product to the "frontpage" collection to see it here...
</a>
</p>
{% endif %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Shopify Documentation](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/showcasing-products/can-i-feature-one-randomly-picked-product#beware-the-caching):

> Shopify's web pages are served cached. Unless a shopper adds a product
>   to his cart, he may be served the same cached page for hours at a
>   time, hence your 'random' product may be the same after a page refresh
>   as it is served from Shopify's 'cache' servers.

A solution could be to show one or more random products with Javascript, see this link for some code: [Shopify random products with Javascript](http://docs.shopify.com/manual/configuration/store-customization/showcasing-products/can-i-feature-randomly-picked-products)